# Dynamically created component executing method twice in communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, create-component

following the [Dynamically Creating Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm) component documentation, I  have created a button in my lightning communitiy that does the following:

1. Creates a modal
2. Creates input buttons based on a an Array

I noticed the following behavior:

When selecting my dynamically created buttons, the method to which they are binded is executed twice on most occasions, sometimes once. I would have expected it to execute once.

I'm not quite sure why this is happening, however, I suspect this to be a bug.

Steps to reproduce:

Create a base component to call the create component method on click (could be on init)

BuggyButton.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Start Bug Reproduction" onclick="{! c.handleBugPanel }" />
        {!v.body}

</aura:component>
```

BuggyButtonController.js

```
({
    handleBugPanel : function(component, event, helper) {
    var modalBody;
    $A.createComponent("c:buggyButtonDynamic", {},
                       function(content, status) {
                           if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                               modalBody = content;
                               component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                                   header: "Select Buttons to log bugs, Make sure you have your Browser Developer Console to Observe the behavior",
                                   body: modalBody, 
                                   showCloseButton: true,
                                   cssClass: "mymodal",
                                   closeCallback: function() {
                                       console.log('You closed the modal');
                                   }
                               })

                           }

                       });
},

})
```

BuggyButtonDynamic.cmp

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>

    {!v.body}

</aura:component>
```

BuggyButtonDynamicController.js

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var someTypes = ['Click Here to Reproduce 1', 'Click Here to Reproduce 2', 'Click Here to Reproduce 3'];
    someTypes.forEach(function(element) {
        $A.createComponent(
        "lightning:input",
        {

            "class" : "slds-text-align_center slds-p-around_small",
            "type": "radio",
            "label": element,
            "name": "Just a name",
            "onclick": cmp.getReference("c.bugGenerator")
        },
        function(newButton, status, errorMessage){
            //Add the new button to the body array
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                var body = cmp.get("v.body");
                body.push(newButton);
                cmp.set("v.body", body);
            }
            else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
                console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
                // Show offline error
            }
            else if (status === "ERROR") {
                console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
                // Show error message
            }
        }
    );            

    });
},
bugGenerator : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    console.log('This should only log once');
},
})
```

Output:

[image]

Unless this is indeed a bug, would anyone happen to know why this behavior produces itself?

Comment: Doesn't have to be communities. I was able to replicate the issue in a regular Salesforce instance.

Comment: Good to know, I had not attempted to do so in LEX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lightning:input` [spec](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/specification) doesn't have an `onclick` handler (though it appears to work, somewhat erratically).

I've changed your `onclick` to `onchange` which is now aligned with the documentation for this base component and I don't experience the double log issue anymore.

EDIT: Further proof the `onclick` event isn't being handled properly is that if you use keyboard arrows to navigate up and down, it will fire only once. My guess here is that since the base component can be so dynamic, `onchange` was the more appropriate event handler to bind value changes to and `onclick` was ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Asides the onclick event not being documented for the component, Product Management seems to have acknowledge this behavior as being a Bug. (according to salesforce support).

> W-5261008 is the bug reference number